# Реализация простого html внутри php кода

Tags: php, html, wordpress, синтаксис

Есть код (приведён ниже), часть которого должна выводить на страницу вот это: На основании отзывов: 1. Но я хочу добавить цвет на число - `<div style="color:#03CA41;"> %d</div>`. Но на страницу выводится надпись с дивами: `На основании отзывов:<div style="color:#03CA41;"> 1</div>`. Помогите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать, не силен в PHP.

```
<article>
        <h2><?php echo ucfirst($review_item_title); ?></h2>
        <div class="score">
        <?php 
            $review_score = $entity_obj->get_custom_field('review_score', false, true);
            $score_out_of_10 = round($review_score * 10);
        ?>
            <span class="achieved"><?php echo esc_html($score_out_of_10); ?></span><span> / 10</span>
            <p class="info"><?php echo sprintf(esc_html__('На основании отзывов:<div style="color:#03CA41;"> %d</div>', 'bookyourtravel'), $reviews_total); ?></p>
            <p class="disclaimer"><?php echo sprintf($guest_reviews_info, $entity_obj->get_title()); ?></p>
        </div>      
        <dl class="chart">
            <?php 
            $total_possible = $reviews_total * 10;  

            $review_fields = $bookyourtravel_review_helper->list_review_fields($post_type, true);
            foreach ($review_fields as $review_field) {
                $field_id = $review_field['id'];
                $field_value = intval($total_possible > 0 ? ($bookyourtravel_review_helper->sum_review_meta_values($base_id, $field_id) / $total_possible) * 10 : 0);

                $field_label = isset($review_field['label']) ? $review_field['label'] : '';
                $field_label = $bookyourtravel_theme_of_custom->get_translated_dynamic_string($bookyourtravel_theme_of_custom->get_option_id_context($context_option_id) . ' ' . $field_label, $field_label);           
            ?>
            <dt><?php echo esc_html($field_label); ?></dt>
            <dd><span><?php echo $field_value; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></dd>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </dl>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `esc_html__` заменяет спецсимволы на HTML сущности в переданном тексте, возвращает отформатированный текст. Заменяются следующие символы: `&, <, >, ", '`. Поэтому выводится код разметки в чистом виде.

В вашем случае надо использовать функцию `__()`, которая переводит текст с использованием текстового домена `bookyourtravel`.

```
<p class="info">
<?php 
  $reviews_total = 5; 
  echo sprintf(__('На основании отзывов:<div style="color:#03CA41;"> %d</div>', 'bookyourtravel'), 
  $reviews_total); ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.